# Compilation of Postgresql using pycparser- header files not found

Tags: postgresql, pycparser

I have installed pycparser that parses C code.

Using pycparser I want to parse an open source project, namely PostgreSQL(version-11.0). I have build it using Visual Studio Express 2017 compiler suite. However, during compilation it cannot find some header files, namely  `windows.h` and `winsock2.h`.

While looking at the directory structure of the build PostgreSQL, I find that it does not have these header files. How to fix this issue?

Also a strange error occurred as:

> postgresql/src/include/c.h:363:2: error: #error must have a working
>   64-bit integer datatype

Note: I am using Windows 10 64-bit platform and postgresql-11.0

The steps are as follows:
                                                                                     I downloaded visual studio 2017, Windows-10 SDK, Active Perl as described in the steps to build from source in PostgreSQL.

After this I open the developer command prompt of Visual Studio and navigate to the folder `postgresql-11.0/src/tools/msvc`

Use command "build" to build postgresql. The build process was successful, but still `windows.h` and `winsock2.h` was not found in directory structure of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please describe the exact steps you used to build PostgreSQL. `windows.h` and `winsock2.h` should be provided by MSVC. The MSVC build process should copy `pg_config.h.win32` to `pg_config.h` so that `HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64` is defined. You must be missing that step, else you shouldn't get that error message.

Comment: I have edited my question and mentioned steps followed by me to build postgresql

Comment: I have seen both files i.e., pg_config.h.win32 and pg_config.h. Both files are exact replica of each other. Still i am getting this error message.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you'll have to teach this pycparser to find them. Note that only GNU make is supported with PostgreSQL, so you are on your own here.

Comment: Sir, i have been successfully able to teach pycparser to find these files i.e., windows.h and winsock2.h. The error that still persists is::
 postgresql/src/include/c.h:363:2: error: #error must have a working 64-bit integer datatype

Comment: I have added more to the answer. No need to call me sir, as I am not of noble extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pycparser, but your problem probably has two aspects to it:

1. You didn't give pycparser the correct list of include directories. The header files you mention are not part of PostgreSQL.

   Maybe you can get the list from the environment of the Visual Studio prompt. I don't have a Windows here to verify that.
2. The error message means that neither `HAVE_LONG_INT_64` nor `HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64` are defined.

   Now `pg_config.h.win32`, which is copied to `pg_config.h` during the MSVC install process, has the following:

   ```
   #if (_MSC_VER > 1200)
   #define HAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 1
   #endif
   ```

   Since you are not using MSVC, you probable don't have `_MSC_VER` set, which causes the error.

   You could define `_MSC_VER` and see if you get to build then.

Essentially you are in a tight spot here, because pycparser is not a supported build procedure, so you'll have to dig into the source and fix things as you go. Without an understanding of the PostgreSQL source and the build process, you probably won't get far.